# Conditional Not Executing

Tags: docker, makefile

I am trying to make different commands execute depending on what OS my original host is. Part of the process involves a docker build, so I do not think that using the `$(OS)` string will help.

My current idea is set the environment variable with a uname in my make file and pass it as an environment variable to docker compose

```
copy:
    cp docker-compose.override.yml.dist docker-compose.override.yml
    cp .env.dist .env

dev: copy restart
    docker-compose exec cli sh

create: export TARGET=$(shell sh -c uname)
create: copy restart 
    TARGET="$(TARGET)" docker-compose exec -T cli make build
    echo $(TARGET) 
    echo $(TARGET)

build: export TARGET=$(shell sh -c uname)
build:
ifeq ($(TARGET),Darwin) 
    cp terra/static.go.dist terra/static.go
    go run builder/main.go
    rm -rf coverage.out
    rm -rf dist/${CLI_VERSION}/osx
    mkdir -p dist/${CLI_VERSION}/osx
    GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o dist/${CLI_VERSION}/osx/mjolnir
    ls -la dist/${CLI_VERSION}/osx/mjolnir
endif
```

Unfortunately, this fails with following output:

```
TARGET="Darwin" docker-compose exec -T cli make build
make: Nothing to be done for 'build'.
echo Darwin
Darwin
echo Darwin
Darwin
```

I will appreciate any pointers as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried setting `build` (and `create/dev/copy`) as `.PHONY` rules ? Also, the `ifeq` rule is evaluated early, so it seems that the `TARGET` value is not `Darwin` when `make` reads the Makefile. Try to run `TARGET=Darwin make create`, you should see a difference, or put a `else` statement to print something and figure out where you are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical setup here is to have a separate Make target for each target platform.

```
TARGET := $(shell uname)
build: build-$(TARGET)
build-Darwin:
        ...
        GOOS=darwin go build ...
```

Once you have that, you can explicitly specify that build target in your command.

```
create: copy restart
        docker-compose run cli make build-$(TARGET)
```

You can also pass Make variables as command-line arguments, which will pass through the layers of Docker more easily than environment variables.

```
create: copy restart
        docker-compose run cli make build TARGET=$(TARGET)
```